# How do I resolve the error: message: 'Undefined attribute level operator conference_users'

Tags: strapi

I have two tables: web_conference is a one to many with the second child table conference_users.

I am attempting to use strapi.entityService to create a new entry to the web_conference and conference_users table like so:

```
const mapInvites = async ()=>{
    return inviteList.conferenceUsers.map(async (item)=>{
        let result = {                    
            userId:item.userId,
            sessionId:item.sessionId
        }
        return result
    })
}

try {
        const newParentObject = await strapi.entityService.create('api::web-conference.web-conference',{
            populate:true,
            data:{
                ownerId:userUid,
                sessionId:sessionId,
                title:title,
                date:date,
                startTime:startTime,
                endTime:endTime,
                publishedAt: publishedAt,
                conference_users:await Promise.all(await mapInvites()),
                inviteRequired:inviteOnly}
        });           
    }
catch (error) {
    console.log(error)    
}
```

However,I keep getting the error

```
message:'Undefined attribute level operator conference_users'
name: 'ValidationError'
```

I have no idea how to solve this and have been stuck for quite some time.

I simply want to be able to populate these tworelational tables. Can someone offer assistance?

I have added the schema.json below:

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "conference_users",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "conference-user",
    "pluralName": "conference-users",
    "displayName": "ConferenceUser",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "userId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sessionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "web_conference": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToOne",
      "target": "api::web-conference.web-conference",
      "inversedBy": "conference_users"
    }
  }
}

{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "web_conferences",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "web-conference",
    "pluralName": "web-conferences",
    "displayName": "WebConference",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "sessionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "unique": true
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "startTime": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "endTime": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "inviteRequired": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "default": false
    },
    "ownerId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "conference_users": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "oneToMany",
      "target": "api::conference-user.conference-user",
      "mappedBy": "web_conference"
    }
  }
}
try {
        const newParentObject = await strapi.entityService.create('api::web-conference.web-conference',{
            data:{
                ownerId:userUid,
                sessionId:sessionId,
                title:title,
                date:date,
                startTime:startTime,
                endTime:endTime,
                publishedAt: publishedAt,
                conference_users:[{id:0,userId:"eeeeee",sessionId:"333-333"}],
                inviteRequired:inviteOnly}
        });           
    }
catch (error) {
    console.log(error)    
}
```

Comment: When you pass relations like that the structure should be `conference_users: [{id:…},{id:…}]`

Comment: but this is what i am doing with the array map and it does not wotk. can you show example?

Comment: you are returning userId if it's a relation it shoudl be an object with `id` props like users: `[{id:1}]`. can you post your schema.json for `web-conference`

Comment: This might be a limitation of strapi, I don’t think you can create relations like this, basically you need to create conference_users in advance and pass them

Comment: Basically in your case making conference_users a repeatable component with attributes userId, sessionId sounds better…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your missing pieces of code:

```js
const mapInvites = async () => {
  return inviteList.conferenceUsers.map(async (item) =>
    await strapi.entityService.create('api::conference-user.conference-user', {
      data: {
        userId: item.userId,
        sessionId: item.sessionId
      }
    })
  )
}
```

```js
try {
  const newParentObject = await strapi.entityService.create('api::web-conference.web-conference', {
    data: {
      ownerId: userUid,
      sessionId: sessionId,
      title: title,
      date: date,
      startTime: startTime,
      endTime: endTime,
      publishedAt: publishedAt,
      conference_users: await Promise.all(mapInvites),
      inviteRequired: inviteOnly
    }
  });
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

not tested so may not work )

Comment: No. thiis will not work. I actually made modification: conference_users: [{userId:"eeeeee",sessionId:"333-333"}] and still no go.

Comment: This because you have create actual relations first (data base entries), also you inversedBy might be other way around.

Comment: I am new to this. canyou site an example of how to do it then?

Comment: Did you try the to change mapInvites, to the one from i posted? If so i can recommend two options: 1. really nice video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kohbOP6Eh9I, 2. join strapi discord, there is #help-questions channel create post there tag me @antokhio.

Comment: I eliminated the need to do a map by assigning the array directly. The map is not the issue. There is a problem with strapi accepting the nested array. Although there are several examples populating data via queries on nested tables, I cannot find a single example of performing mutations on nested tables. In the end I had to resort on performing raw queriesto add or update my tables. Very clumsy method that does not take advantage of strapi's entity framework.

Comment: It's works with components for 100%, with relations it's 50% / 50%, the regular way of doing this is first create or get id's of content you want to append then push array with id. But i only do hasOne, hasMany, two way relations is dodgy on my taste. Also highly unrecommended to use userId, ownerId and so on. This breaks when you use data import/export. You should use relations for that...

Comment: OK. so the last suggestion worked. thanks for your assistance.